# Google drive api search query problems

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

I'm using google drive to find contracts every contract has been uploaded by an app written in c# .net 4.0/4.5 with several properties like firstname, lastname, location,.... 
I'm using a service account with a certificate instead of a real gmail or whatsoever.

I have no problem searching for anything but if I select all possible properties and it aren't that much properties I get this error 500 backend error.

This is the generated query by my app which gives the 500 backend error:

```
mimeType != 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false
and (properties has { key='LastName' and value='test' and visibility='PUBLIC' } 
or fullText contains 'test' 
or properties has { key='Employer' and value='test' and visibility='PUBLIC' } 
or properties has { key='FirstName' and value='test' and visibility='PUBLIC' } 
or properties has { key='Location' and value='test' and visibility='PUBLIC' } 
or properties has { key='Profession' and value='test' and visibility='PUBLIC' }) 
and (properties has { key='Type' and value='contract' and visibility='PUBLIC' })
```

Edit:

I just noticed that it's not always a backend error sometimes i get an Internal Error [500]
And sometimes it just works like it should.

Comment: I wonder if the request is to long. Request to the api are sent as HTTP GET which has a string limit of 2000 by tacking that much stuff on the end it may be to long.

Comment: it's not the string limit as it sometimes works, sometimes it's an error 500 backend error and sometimes it's an error 500 internal error. for now i put a limit to max 5 properties in 1 search. i think this is just some minor bug in the google drive api as the properties search is not that old.